# Finding the lengths of $AC$ and $AD$

Tags: geometry

> Triangle $ABC$ is right-angled at $A$. The angle bisector from $A$ meets $BC$ at $D$.  If $CD=1$ and $BD=AD+1$, find the lengths of $AC$ and $AD$.

I have tried to set up a equation with $AD$ and $AC$ using cosine rule.

Comment: Let $AD=x$ and $AC=y.$ Then $x$ will satisfy a fourth degree polynomial namely $x^4+2x^3-4x-2 = 0.$ It has only one positive solution which is $-\frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt[4] 3} {\sqrt 2} + \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2}.$ So $x = -\frac 1 2 + \frac {\sqrt[4] 3} {\sqrt 2} + \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2} = 1.29663$ (approx.). Once you got $x$ you will find $y$ by the formula $y = \frac {x(x+2)} {\sqrt 2 (x+1)}.$ Thus $y=1.316$ (approx.).

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough depiction of the problem, where $\overline{AD}$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$, and $BD=AD+1$. Note that $\angle BAD=\angle DAC=45º$.

[image: Image of problem]

Using Law of Sines to the lower subtriangle, we have:
$$\frac{\sin\angle C}{AD}=\frac{\sin\angle DAC}{DC}$$
Rearranging and simplifying, we get:
$$\sin\angle C=AD\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
Applying Law of Sines to the upper subtriangle, we have:
$$\frac{\sin\angle B}{AD}=\frac{\sin\angle BAD}{BD}$$
Rearranging and simplifying and also noting that $\sin B=\cos C$ we get:
$$\cos\angle C=\frac{AD\sqrt{2}}{2(AD+1)}$$
Using the Pythagorean Identity, we get that:
$$\sin^2\angle C+\cos^2\angle C=1$$
$$\left(\frac{AD\sqrt{2}}{2(AD+1)}\right)^2+\left(AD\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2=1$$

Solving for AD (I used a graphical method, so it may be a little off), we get $AD\approx1.294$. Then, the hypotenuse $\overline{BC}$ of the large triangle is $AD+2$, and the leg $\overline{AC}$ is given by $BC\cos\angle C$, so we get that:
$$AC=(AD+2)\left(\frac{AD\sqrt{2}}{2(AD+1)}\right)$$
Which is approximately 1.316.